# How to write NSArrays and NSDictionaries for getting and to Join two table's data into another table SQLite, iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, tableview

When I am joining two tables data into another `tableView` using sqlite it getting Null value how to write `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.And also how to set the objects and keys. below is my database class

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getData
{
    sqlite3 *dbobj;
    NSString *dbpath  =[DBClass connectdb];
    NSMutableArray *readArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbobj)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

        //**** NSString *string=@"SELECT name FROM emptable";
        NSString *string=@"SELECT EMP_ID, Age, DEPT FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON COMPANY.ID = DEPARTMENT.EMP_ID";
        ;
        const char *query=[string UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbobj, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *readDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"DEPT"];

                //[readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"Age"];

                [readArray addObject:readDic];
                // NSLog(@"%@",readDic);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",readArray);
    sqlite3_close(dbobj);
    return readArray;

}
```

The below one is the my `JointviewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    array=[DBClass getData];
    for( NSDictionary *obj in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);

        [data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"DEPT"]];
        //[data addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Age"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"\n%d",[data count]);
    [Table reloadData];

}
```

Comment: your query is wrong. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: What is the procedure to execute my query?

Comment: if u wanna check if it's working or not, you can see that in sqlite browser's "Execute SQL".

Comment: Am not asking that one.I want to do Join my query what is the procedure for code in Objective-C.

Comment: R u getting value in array? what is the output of NSLog(@"\n%d",[data count]);?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify tablename before columnname. i.e. from which table this particular column belongs.

See this example of `inner join` and try to relate your code.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

Comment: Am asking about NSArrays and NSMutableDictionaries not Query.